# Названия методов класса из строк Nodejs

Tags: node.js, классы, методы

Хочу провернуть в Node следующее, допустим есть класс:

```
class Some {    
  constructor(methods) {
    for (var i in methods) {
      this[methods[i]] = this.func;
    }
  }

  func(data, callback) {
    console.log("Имя метода: " + this.func.name);
  }
}
```

В классе есть метод func, а в конструктор передается массив строк. Каким образом мне сделать так, чтобы при обращении к методу, равному любой из этих строк, вызывался метод func, причем таким образом, чтобы внутри func я мог знать название конкретного метода, к которому обратились:

```
var methods = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
var some = new Some(methods);
some.two({}, () => {

});
```

Или то, что я хочу невозможно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class Some {
  constructor(methods) {
    for (var m of methods) {
      this[m] = this.func.bind(this, m)
    }
  }

  func(name, data) {
    console.log(name, data)
  }
}

var some = new Some(['one', 'two', 'three']);
some.one(1)
some.two(2)
some.three(3)
```